# Chromeで日本語の禁則処理が効かない

Tags: css, google-chrome

Firefoxやsafariでは長音や短い"ッ"などの禁則処理が効いているのに、Chromeではきちんと処理されません。`Word-break: break-strict;`を`body`に適用しても改行されてしまいます。Chromeできちんと禁則処理を適用さすにはどのように（どこに？）記述すればよろしいでしょうか。

Chromeのバージョンは56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)、Windows 10で使用しています。

#### 追記

```
body {
 word-break: normal;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

でも駄目でした。

Answer (score 14):

[Chrome58以降](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=735539)、`lang="ja"` 属性と `line-break: strict` を付けることで、長音や拗音の前での行分割を抑制することができるようです。

---

現在CSSで禁則処理などを規定しているのは [CSS Text Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/) という文章なので、これを調べてみました。なお2017年12月現在も Working Draft なので最終稿ではありません。

長音（`ー` U+30FC）や小さいひらがな・カタカナ（例えば `ッ` U+3085）は記号による行分割という枠組みで [`line-break` プロパティ](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#line-break-property)に記載があります。これはいわゆる禁則処理の強さを指定するもので、英単語内などでの分割を制御する `word-break` プロパティよりも下位の指定です。

> The following breaks are forbidden in strict line breaking and allowed in normal and loose:
>
> - breaks before Japanese small kana or the Katakana-Hiragana prolonged sound mark: i.e. characters with the Unicode Line Break property CJ. (See LineBreak.txt in [UNICODE].)

これらの文字は `line-break: strict` では分割禁止、`line-break: normal` や `line-break: loose` では分割可とあります。省略した場合の `line-break: auto` ではUAが自由に禁則文字を決めていいとあるので、Firefoxでは含まれていたのがChromeでは含まれていない、で納得できます。

**結論1：長音や小さいカナを禁則文字に含めたければ `line-break: strict` を明示すべき。**

---

しかし `line-break: strict` を指定してもChromeでは解決しません。期待通りに禁則処理が行われている [Test Suite](http://test.csswg.org/harness/test/css-text-3_dev/spec/css-text-3/section/5/alpha/css3-text-line-break-jazh-018/) と見比べたところ、Test Suite では `lang="ja"` 属性が使われていました。これを指定することで、問題の文字による禁則処理が行われるようになりました。

`lang="ja"` の場合にのみ前述の禁則文字が適用される、という記述は見つけられませんでしたし、実際 Firefox は lang 属性に関わらず適用するようです。とはいえ、

> Authors should language-tag their content accurately for the best typographic behavior.

と[書かれている](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#languages)ことですし、指定しておくに越したことはないでしょう。

**結論2：`lang="ja"` も指定すべき。**

---

```css
div { background-color: #afa; width: 5em; }
```

```html
指定なし
<div>
あいうえおーかきく<br>
あいうえおッかきく
</div>
word-break: break-all
<div style="word-break: break-all">
あいうえおーかきく<br>
あいうえおッかきく
</div>
line-break: strict
<div style="line-break: strict">
あいうえおーかきく<br>
あいうえおッかきく
</div>
lang="ja"
<div lang="ja">
あいうえおーかきく<br>
あいうえおッかきく
</div>
lang="ja" line-break: strict
<div lang="ja" style="line-break: strict">
あいうえおーかきく<br>
あいうえおッかきく
</div>
```

Comment: ご丁寧な回答、どうもありがとうございました。他のブラウザでは動作するようなので、Chromeについてはしばらく待ってみます。